# How to output in columns using Bash built-in `printf` where source contains colours?

Tags: shell-script, printf

The code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
ips[0]='192.168.0.1'
ips[1]='192.168.0'
ips[2]='255.255.255.256'
ips[3]='123.123.123.123.123'
ips[4]='a.b.c.d'
ips[5]='255.255.255.255'
ips[6]='0.0.0.0'
ips[7]='192.168.1.1'
ips[8]='4.2.2.2'

regex="^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})[.]){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})$"

regexVar=$(printf "\033[33mSaved in a VARIABLE\033[0m")
regexStr=$(printf "\033[34mIs a STRING\033[0m")
validOut=$(printf "\033[32mValid\033[0m")
invalidOut=$(printf "\033[31mInvalid\033[0m")
noQuotes="NO quotes"
singleQuotes="Single quotes"
doubleQuotes="Double quotes"

printStyle="%-25s %-10s %-20s %-10s\n"
printTitle=$(printf "${printStyle}" "IP Address" "Validity" "Regex" "Quote Type")
print2ndLine=$(printf "${printStyle}" "====================" "==========" "====================" "==========")

function validIP1a() {
    echo "${printTitle}"
    echo "${print2ndLine}"
    for (( i=0; i<${#ips[@]}; i++ )); do
        if [[ "${ips[i]}" =~ $regex ]]; then
            printf "${printStyle}" "${ips[i]}" "${validOut}" "${regexVar}" "${noQuotes}"
        else
            printf "${printStyle}" "${ips[i]}" "${invalidOut}" "${regexVar}" "${noQuotes}"
        fi
    done
}

validIP1a
```

The output is:

[image: output can't be aligned]

The expected output is:

[image: expected aligned output]

Why I can't get the expected result? How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `printf` counts the characters in the escape code that sets the color; it doesn't know they don't actually print. You'd need to put them outside the fixed-length formatted (`%-20s`) strings. Compare the two `printf`s here:

```
#!/bin/bash
green=$'\033[32m'
yellow=$'\033[33m'
normal=$'\033[0m'

printf "1234567890123456789012345678901234567\n";
printf "%-20s %s\n" "${yellow}some string${normal}"  "next col"
printf "${yellow}%-20s${normal} %s\n" "some string"  "next col"
```

The output should look like this:

[image: sample output]

Of course, if the color can change, we can put it in another variable:

```
printf "%s%-20s${normal} %s\n" "$green" "some string"  "next col"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to count the characters in `validOut` and `invalidOut`; I count more than 10 in each of them:

```
#                                11   11111
#                    1   2245678901   23456
  validOut=$(printf "\033[32mValid\033[0m")
invalidOut=$(printf "\033[31mInvalid\033[0m")
```

Remember that poor `printf` cannot possibly know that some of those characters are invisible and make color changes... You requested a left-aligned field of at least 10 characters, and then proceeded to fill it with strings having more than 10 characters; no wonder the result is not vertically aligned.